# SafeApiKit.estimateSafeTransaction always returns 0 on Polygon network

Tags: gnosis-safe

When I call SafeApiKit.estimateSafeTransaction with the selected network as `https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global/`, it always returns "safeTxGas": "0" regardless of the input parameters, while other networks work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As from 1.3.0 contracts estimating `safeTxGas` is not necesary (previously it was to prevent `eth_estimageGas` taking the short path and underestimating), and on other networks different than mainnet the only version currently supported is  1.3.0 we decided to disable estimation, as it's also a lot of overhead for RPC nodes